# Is there any way to transform cdata sections of an XML document with an XSL template?

Tags: xml, xslt

Take this XML.

Is there a way for me to transform the contents of the CDATA section with XSLT?

Answer (score 3):

Read this article - [CDATA Sections](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/cdata.html)

> SUMMARY:Within the XSLT stylesheet,
>   the CDATA section is purely a utility
>   to stop you from having to escape all
>   the '<' etc. The goal you're aiming
>   for is copying something that you have
>   in your XML source directly into your
>   HTML output. The xsl:copy-of element
>   is designed precisely for this
>   purpose. xsl:copy-of will give an
>   exact copy of whatever you select,
>   including attributes and content.

XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<know>
   <title/>
   <topic title="" href="">
     <![CDATA[
         Text
        ]]>
    </p>    
   </topic>
</know>
```

xsl Document.

```
<xsl:stylesheet  
   version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template  match="know">
     <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="topic">
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/> 
             <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/> 
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

XSLT handles CDATA sections as just normal text, so you can treat them as you would text nodes. Note that XSLT does not retain CDATA sections as separate from surrounding text. Thus if you have

```
<foo>bar <![CDATA[baz]]> qux</foo>
```

The source tree will be

- Document

  - Element: foo

    - Text: "bar baz qux"